# jqueries switchClass with multiple Classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, toggle, semantic-ui

I am using semantic-ui and would like to switch a containers class from

```
six wide column
```

to

```
sixteen wide column
```

with

```
$( '.grid.slider .six.wide.column' ).switchClass( 'six', 'sixteen', 1000 );
$( '.grid.slider .six.wide.column' ).switchClass( 'six wide column', 'sixteen wide column', 1000 );
```

Both is not working. With the first I get

```
wide column sixteen
```

which is not correcly interpreted by the css-framework
With the second all classes get replaced with only

```
sixteen
```

so how to switch all classes with right order?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But then no animation is done even it could be handled directly in any CSS rule

Comment: right syntax `switchClass( "yourclass", "switchclass", TIMEINTERVAL, "ANIMATION" )`

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/

Comment: @A.Wolff my mistake. I didn't realise `switchClass` was a jQueryUI method.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OP should have mention it for sure :)

Comment: You mean CSS framework doesn't work because order of setted classes? `wide column sixteen` != `sixteen wide column`

Comment: @ A. Wolff  wide column sixteen != sixteen wide column is correct, @Gautam Jha the syntax is correct. But the does not reflect the purposed order

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest you to use the jQuery attr with function:

```
$( '.grid.slider .six.wide.column' ).attr('class', function(index, attr) {
   return attr.replace('six', 'sixteen');
});
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. This is working. But missing animation as switchClass does automaticaly. Would be nice to have animation.

Comment: @user1308302 You may apply first your switchClass to obtain the animation desired and after change the class attributes, or you may create your own animation. The last possibility is to create youyr own  switchClass function

Comment: My desired animation is a transition into the target classes. A two stepped classes change would not achive that. So its all because the right writing order of classes is needed. Maybe I have to leave animation behind.

Comment: @user1308302 i suggest you to leave the animation behind. Do you accept my answer and upvote?